# Render layer- or render pass-like options when you can't use Film | Transparency?

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes, render-layers, render-passes

I have a scene containing

1. An object
2. An animated screen with an image texture/transparency material, which passes in front of the camera, adding a mist-like effect to the scene
3. A background/ground, etc
4. Environmental lighting

In the animation, Screen 2 passes in front of the camera, causing the scene to appear misted or muddy behind Screen 2.

I would like to "hold out" Item 1, the primary object, and produce a series of rendered images in which Item 1 appears as it does with the "screen" down but the remainder of the image appears at each point to reflect the screen's progress.... making the rest of the scene progressively mistier.

The rub: I need the cube to reflect the environmental lighting effects of the complete scene (less the animated scrim).... I can handle this in instances when my background can be transparent, but in this case I need my environment and lighting because of their contributions to my object.

This is a gimped up file, but includes the animated scrim.  All input welcome.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to dissect this effect from a reference and show an example of the desired outcome?

Comment: The desired outcome portion of my sample image shows what I would like to have: The primary element unchanged by the mist screen, but those portions of the environment also behind the screen appropriately influenced.